# Appending to a file error - PYTHON

Tags: python, file, append

Please bear with my as I am new to python and am learning by creating simple programs. Recently I started making my own program that generates a file and allows the user to choose things and store them in each file. In this example I was going for a song playlist generator. Although it was difficult I soldiered through until I came across this error that I couldn't fix. It was with the opening of a file.

This is the Code

```
cont = "0"
log = 0
data = open("songs.txt", "r")
songs = data.readlines()
songs.sort()


while log < 20:
    cont = input("Do you want to make a playlist? [Yes or No]")
    while cont == "yes":
        print ("1. ", songs[0],"2. ", songs[1],"3. ", songs[2],"4. ", songs[3],"5. ", songs[4],"6. ", songs[5],"7. ", songs[6],"8. ", songs[7],"9. ", songs[8],"10. ", songs[9],"11. ", songs[10],"12. ", songs[11],"13. ", songs[12],"14. ", songs[13],"15. ", songs[14],"16. ", songs[15],"17. ", songs[16],"18. ", songs[17],"19. ", songs[18],"20. ", songs[19])
        new = "playlist" + str(log) + ".txt"
        print(new)
        log = log + 1
        cont = "no"
        choice = int(input("Please enter the first choice of song you would like in your playlist [Type the allocated number please]"))
        choice1 = choice - 1
        "playlist" + str(log) + ".txt".append(songs[choice1])
```

However, my code is supposed to allow the user to choose songs from my print function and then add them to the playlist generatored and then repeat this for as many playlists they want. Now my code is giving me an error message.

```
File "playlists.py", line 18, in <module>
"playlist" + str(log) + ".txt".append(songs[choice1])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

What is this Error stating and also how can I overcome it.

Thanks in advance and anticipation!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that last line? You are trying to call the function `append()` on the string `".txt"`. You can't append to strings, only lists, hence this error.

Comment: Have you read a single tutorial on how to work with files in Python?

Comment: @SCB How could I convert the file into a list format?

Comment: @Barmar I have tried but it made little sense to me...

Comment: It's not really that much different from most other languages. You open the file, then call functions or methods to read from it or write to it. You got it right for `songs.txt`.

Comment: @Barmar I understand what your saying but the problem was songs.txt was creates by me before hand. In this program I am trying to create a file through the program (which it does) and then call this file back, open it and then allow the user to choose what songs they want to put in. At the moment my program generates the file I want, however the problem is calling it back due to the name changing every loop. (I will make it loop continuously once I've worked it out) This is the problem. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: @SCB See above please

Comment: The answer isn't to convert to a list. I think there is a problem with your logic. What are you trying to output?

Comment: @SCB I'm trying to create a program that generates playlists in new files to be easily accessible to the user.

Comment: What does it matter who created the `songs.txt` file? You understood enough Python to know that you needed to write `open("songs.txt")` to read from it. How could you not know that you also need to use `open()` to *write* to the playlist file?

Comment: @Barmar I do know I need to do that. The problem is me opening the file. To open the file you need to type in the file's name. The problem with this - for me - is that the file name changes every round for me so I don't know how to write some code that looks at the file name generated and opens that. The problem is the file recognizing what the file is called and opening it. I can't write code saying open this file because the next time around, the playlist will have another name. This is what I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that this line:

```
"playlist" + str(log) + ".txt".append(songs[choice1])
```

is just super wrong/sort of like pseudocode. To append to a text file requires you open it for appending and then write to it. Do this like so:

```
with open("playlist" + str(log) + ".txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(str(songs[choice1]))
```